# How do you traverse a javascript object via an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an array of strings to access a value nested within an object.

Is there a utility for this already?

```
let obj= {
  one: {
    two: {
      thee: "test"
    }
  }
}

let values= ["one", "two", "three"]

function accessObjectWithArray(obj, arr) {
    // returns "test"
}
```

Comment: lodash's `_.get(obj, arr)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce` to iterate through the array of properties:

```js
const obj={one:{two:{three:"test"}}};
const values= ["one", "two", "three"];

const accessObjectWithArray = (obj, arr) => arr.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], obj);
console.log(accessObjectWithArray(obj, values));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into js to do this, but you can make a nice recursive function to do it:

```js
let obj= {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: "test"
    }
  }
}

let values= ["one", "two", "three"]

function accessObjectWithArray(obj, arr) {
    if (!arr.length) return obj;
    return accessObjectWithArray(obj[arr[0]], arr.slice(1));
}

console.log(accessObjectWithArray(obj, values));
```

*Note: You had a typo in the `three` property which I have fixed*

Answer (score 0):

[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) has a nice `get` function for this:

```js
let obj= {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: "test"
    }
  }
}

console.log(_.get(obj, ['one', 'two', 'three']))

console.log(_.get(obj, 'one.two.three'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```